# Convert Entity Object into IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework

I have a SQL database containging a Contants table containing people contacts records.
Im passing a contact record object to a ContactsDetailsControl() method to display that contacts details for the selected record.

ItemsListBox.ItemsSource wants a list of IEnumerable objects

Whats the sinmplest way to convert this Entity Object to IEnumberable without having to do something like the below?

> ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = new List().Add(contact);

```
public ContactsDetailsControl(ProActive.Contact contact)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   List<Contact> l = new List<Contact>();
   l.Add(contact);

   ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = contact[];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below is a generic way to make an IEnumerable containing a single object.

```
public ContactsDetailsControl(ProActive.Contact contact)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = MakeMeEnumerable<Contact>(contact);
}

private IEnumerable<T> MakeMeEnumerable<T>(T Entity)
{
    yield return Entity;
}
```

Comment: Do you even need the the generic type argument on the callsite?

Answer (score 2):

A simple, but not pretty, way of doing it is using [Enumerable.Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Repeat(contact, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = new [] { contact };
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always have to create a new list and add your contact to it. A single contact is not the same as a list of contacts and you cant (and shouldnt be able) to cast directly to it.

You may want to create another class that inherits from `List<contact>` which you could instanciate and it load the contacts you need on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The question no one seems to be asking is why are you using a ListBox when you said you are trying to display information for a single record?

If you want to apply a template to the item, use a ContentPresenter and set the ContentTemplate. (Internally that's what the listbox does when it generates the visuals for the items in its source).